# Using Pandas to aggregate value based on another column aggregated index

Tags: pandas

my `df` looks like this:

```
student_id,    coll_type,  grad_year,   completed    
1001           2-year        NA            N          
1001           2-year        NA            N           
1001           2-year      2003            Y           
1001           2-year      2004            Y           
1001           4-year      2007            Y            

1002           4-year        NA            N              
1002           2-year        NA            N                   
1002           2-year        NA            N                   

1003           4-year        NA            N                    
1003           4-year        NA            N                    

1004           2-year        NA            N                   
1004           4-year      2005            Y  
1004           4-year      2007            Y
```

My goal is get this:

```
student_id,    coll_type,  year_year,  completed            
1001           2-year      2003           Y           
1001           4-year      2007           Y            

1002           4-year        NA           N              
1002           2-year        NA           N                   

1003           4-year        NA           N                    

1004           2-year        NA           N                   
1004           4-year      2005           Y
```

**In summary:**

- The goal is to group by `['student_id', 'coll_type']` and then `aggregrate` by the earliest `'grad_year'` (*if any*) and "choose" its corresponding `'completed'` value.
- if the `'grad_year'` value is "only" `NA` for that group `['student_id', 'coll_type']`, then we select `NA` and its corresponding `'completed'` value, which is always `N`

**What did I do?**

```
df.groupby(['student_id', 'coll_type'])
  .agg({
grad_year = ('grad_year', 'min'),
completed = ('completed', 'max')
})
```

but it does not work, since I am choosing different `min` and `max` value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) on the boolean Series of the NA-status of the grad_year:

```
out = df.loc[df['grad_year']
              .notna()
              .groupby([df['student_id'], df['coll_type']])
              .idxmax()
             ]
```

output:

```
    student_id coll_type  grad_year completed
2         1001    2-year     2003.0         Y
4         1001    4-year     2007.0         Y
6         1002    2-year        NaN         N
5         1002    4-year        NaN         N
8         1003    4-year        NaN         N
10        1004    2-year        NaN         N
11        1004    4-year     2005.0         Y
```

Comment: thanks for composing the answer. could you please write code in the way I have like `.agg{...}` I have other variables as well where I am selecting `first` `last` etcs

Comment: This is not an `agg` type of answer, please provide a complete example (or open a new question)